# Having problems labelling nodes in semplot > sempaths

Tags: r, plot

Any help would be appreciated with regards to labelling nodes from a CFA model (calculated using `Lavaan`) and plot using the `semPlot` package.

I am not having problems with specifying the model. However, when it comes to plotting the output (fit3) I keep getting an error whenever I try to change the node labels from the one's present in the dataset to more publish-friendly one's. The error I get is:

> Error in if (border) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The code for the plot is as follows:

```
semPaths(fit3,  what = "std", layout = "tree", title = FALSE,  style = "lisrel", 
         nodeLabels = c("Internet\nAddiction", "Engagement", "Withdrawal",
                        "Conflict","Relapse","Tolerance","Mood mod","Salience"),
         sizeMan = 10, sizeLat = 10)
```

Also to note, I don't have any problems with plotting the model until I include the argument `nodeLabels = c("Inter...etc.)`. I have also tried creating a list of label names `(lbls = c("Inter...etc.)` and them called the list using `nodeLabels = lbls`, but this leads to the same error message as I quoted above

> "Error in if (border) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Any help and guidance with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, the error indicates that you did not provide enough labels for the model.

In your case, `semPlot` expects labels for the latent variables, the manifest variables, AND the intercepts. I guess you skipped the labels for the intercepts.

If you do not need the intercepts, try to include `intercepts = FALSE`

```
semPaths(fit3,  what = "std", layout = "tree", title = FALSE,  style = "lisrel", 
     nodeLabels = c("Internet\nAddiction", "Engagement", "Withdrawal",
                    "Conflict","Relapse","Tolerance","Mood mod","Salience"),
     sizeMan = 10, sizeLat = 10,
     intercepts = FALSE)
```

In case you want the keep the intercepts, you have to define a label for each intercept.